# Designing/Implementing MVC from Scratch

Tags: php, mysql, html, model-view-controller

I want to create my very first web app using HTML, MySQL, PHP and the Model View Controller. It will be very simple for starters: a couple of pages that allows users to input/delete data to/from the database and display the contents of the database.

However I am new to MVC, and I really wish I could have found MVC tutorials appropriate for beginners like myself on how to actually implement it using simple code examples. I only found advanced examples which makes the learning curve unnecessarily steeper. I guess I will have to create one here.

My questions are, how do I get started with designing this MVC from scratch for a very very simple web app? How do I separate the Model, the View and the Controller in code? What steps should I take and how? How do I implement the model as business entity classes, the view as HTML, and the controller as scripts that glue everything together? (assuming my understanding of this is correct) Can anyone recommend clear and  straight forward tutorials on how to actually implement MVC for beginners like myself? (I could not find any).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why build from scratch? There are plenty of MVCs out there, for any language you prefer...

Comment: Thanks for your reply Am. I read that on Wikipedia. I was not sure what was the best approach for a beginner to truely understand MVC. I could be wrong but using C++ as an example, learning to code a linked list from scratch (at least once)will teach the beginner a lot more than just using a library like Boost from the beginning. Not sure if my logic is correct

Comment: I think in this case the approach is not that good. since a good MVC has a lot more then just he separation of concepts. It encapsulates a lot of ideas.  you can read this book: http://apress.com/book/view/1430210079, it explains very well how MVC was born and what exact needs it answers (specifically the C# MVC)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are plenty of frameworks to help you with this. I would recommend using CakePHP, http://www.cakephp.org. It has good documentation, a large community and a lot of tutorials!

Comment: Please note that most of current PHP "MVC" frameworks implements something that's not a true MVC. In other words: they implement that pattern wrong. At least Symfony/ZF/Kohana doesn't handle it. I'm pretty sure CakePHP (I've never used it) doesn't implement it correct as well.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Dale. I saw CakePHP as one of many frameworks available for PHP. I will start researching that now. Just curious though, is designing MVC from scratch that difficult? Thanks again for recommending CakePHP

Comment: @Crozin, thanks for your reply. How did you learn MVC: from scratch or a framework? Which will benefit the beginner more? Which framework would you recommend if any? Thanks for your insight

Comment: @dale, CakePHP looks interesting

Comment: @dale, CakePHP's documentation looks good so far

Comment: @01010011: I've learnt from the scratch.You asked me what PHP FW I could recommend. Well... I'm using [Symfony](http://symfony-project.org) - it's a really good and powerful FW with great community.

I think it's a better idea to learn from scratch cause it's important to know how some things work. When you're learning form FW you learn only how to use these "tools", not how they work. Such basic knowledge is required for every programmer.

Comment: @Crozin, I will look at symfony, thanks. Can you recommend any tutorials for learning from scratch for the beginner?

Comment: Symfony takes some time to learn. Try to start with Code Igniter.

Answer (score 2):

When you want to do MVC the first time, you do not start from scratch. CakePHP is a really good recommendation by Dale to start with. When you have done it many times and understand what MVC is about, then you will be able to implement an MVC without a framework.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @sibidiba. Judging from your repsonce it sounds like MVC is complicated, especially for beginners. I am new to PHP. When I think about this MVC, I thinking in terms of C++ classes and how to modularize my code to seperate the 3 parts. Yeah, I like the documentation so far, logged onto the IRC chat already, and I cannot wait to see what CakePHP is like.

Comment: MVC is not complicated at all. I guess you already know the concept of it. But it is different to use, and to implement an MVC framework. For the latter you have to deeply understand MVC's concept, and the language you are working with, and the typical usage scenarios.
Never ever start from scratch, except if you really, really have to.
Thinking that your code without any prior experience will be better and cleaner and more functional then the well tested code of dozens of experienced programmers is a mistake every programmer (including me) makes way too often.

Comment: For CakePHP, this is a great resource: http://book.cakephp.org/

And this: http://api13.cakephp.org/classes

What I really like in CakePHP, that is is so simple, that you can easily look into its source code when you are in doubt how it works.

Answer (score 1):

There is no quick path for this.

If you really want to build an MVC, go over some existing ones. Read their documentation and try understanding why they made certain choices (security, robustness, etc).

You will find [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) a good list of existing MVCs.

Comment: @Am, I'm reading the CakePHP now and it looks interesting.

Answer (score 1):

A good tutorial to understand how MVC works is [this one](http://oreilly.com/php/archive/mvc-intro.html). It shows you how to create a framework from scratch but I'd suggest you use an existing framework if you want to do something more complex.

Comment: @eduardoks, thanks for your reply and the link. I am diving head first into CakePHP and when I am ready, then I will spend time trying to create MVC on my own.

Answer (score 1):

I think symfony2 would be a right choice as the codebase is very extensive and also its enterprise level scaling is more robust than Zend framework....

Comment: sorry for a v.v. late reply...

Comment: +1 No worries. Thanks for the reply. Currently, I'm using CodeIgniter, Django and soon, I'll also be using Rails. I don't even think about writing anything from scratch anymore.

Comment: yes, right you're @Anthony, writing from scratch is a real pain & time consuming task for developers who need rapid, working solutions...

Answer (score 1):

Fwiw, all server side frameworks (PHP included) cannot be MVC in the context of the-original-SmallTalk MVC (e.g., a client-side context) because of the lack of a live event loop. The closest that server side MVC can come to Smalltalk MVC is something like Model2 ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_2 ).

Answer (score 0):

This could be a good starting point: [MVC in PHP](http://php-html.net/tutorials/model-view-controller-in-php/) is a tutorial covering the basics of MVC.